# Let translation-golf begin: Fragmento de "Breakfast at Tiffany's" sobre los miedos del personaje principal

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

El otro día Carlos Alejo propuso que realizáramos un juego: a ver quién es capaz de traducir un texto con el menor número de caracteres manteniendo su sentido original y utilizando un lenguaje homogéneo (variantes regionales de un solo lugar). ¿Empezamos?

Las reglas están en [This is translation-golf! The translation with the least number of characters wins!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/1674)

Para empezar he extraído este fragmento de "Breakfast at Tiffany's", de Truman Capote ([fuente](https://www.bustle.com/articles/121359-25-of-the-best-book-quotes-of-all-time)):

> You call yourself a free spirit, a 'wild thing,' and you're terrified somebody's gonna stick you in a cage. Well baby, you're already in that cage. You built it yourself. And it's not bounded in the west by Tulip, Texas, or in the east by Somali-land. It's wherever you go. Because no matter where you run, you just end up running into yourself.

En España este libro (así como la película basada en ella) se tradujo como "Desayuno con diamantes". La actriz que protagonizó la película es Audrey Hepburn, así que teniéndola a ella en mente propongo esta traducción básica y algo larga, incluso ortopédica (oculta para no condicionar):

> Te llamas a ti misma espíritu libre, una "cosa salvaje", y estás aterrorizada de que alguien te encierre en una jaula. Pues bien, cariño, tú ya estás en esa jaula. La has construido tú misma. Y no está limitada al oeste de Tulip, Texas, o al este de Somalilandia. Está allí donde vas. Porque no importa adónde corras, siempre acabas corriendo hacia ti mismo.

Número de caracteres: 280 (letras, no cuentan los signos de puntuación).

¿Quién es capaz de proponer una traducción con menos caracteres?

Aceptaré la respuesta que en los próximos siete días sea capaz de ofrecer la traducción válida con el menor número de caracteres.
¿Te animas a participar? Va, que esto está chupado :)

---

Clasificación final tras los siete días de competición:

1. [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20242/1674) - 116 caracteres
2. [guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20250/1674) - 118
3. [Astrar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20255/1674) - 159
4. [JMVanPelt](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20249/1674) - 161
5. [Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20246/1674) - 195
6. [aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20253/1674) - 222

Comment: ¡Qué bien que hayas tomado la iniciativa! Yo pensaba empezar con frases más breves, pero ya que estamos, vamos allá...

Comment: He cambiado el título de la pregunta porque ya está en la lista de _Hot Network Questions_, para que se note que es un nuevo tipo de pregunta al incluir la tipología de la misma. A ver si así llamamos más la atención sobre esta nueva propuesta.

Comment: I think the person who posts the text to be translated should put his own translation in an Answer (not in the question).  It takes too much effort to ignore the first version when it's sitting right there on the screen, right below the original.

Comment: @aparente001 that's a good point. We decided to have the OP suggest a translation themselves, so that we do not use this as a translation service. What I just did is to change the format of the suggestion to [spoilers](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) so that it does not show up unless you hover the text. Do you think this solves the problem?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo buena idea lo del título. A todo esto, tu idea de juego se ha demostrado muy exitosa, ¡olé!

Comment: @fedorqui - very nice.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo and Fedorqui, but it would be nice to be able to vote separately for the text submission as well as the translation submission.

Comment: @aparente001 we had some debate about this [while discussing the rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/1674). My point here is that even though it is a game, the question has to stick to site's rules, where effort must be shown. The intention of the translation, thus, is not to win but to show that, and hence (at least in my case) I went for a dummy translation without many nuances, just to agree with the rule. But, again, we are just starting, so your suggestion may be followed by the next person opening a challenge and may be well received.

Comment: @fedorqui - Oh, I see, the translation in the question is a dummy translation, and when we vote on the question, we ignore the dummy translation.  Got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Español de España (actual), 116 caracteres.

> "Salvaje", alma libre te crees, y temes ser enjaulada. Lo estás, nena, en una propia. No acaba en Lugo o en Irán. Lo abarca todo: donde vas, la jaula eres tú.

- Uso de los dos puntos para explicar la conclusión y ahorrarme el "porque".
- Al decir "lo estás" se entiende que es ahora al usar el presente, luego sobra el "ya".
- "Propia" se usa en el sentido de "que pertenece de manera exclusiva a alguien" y en el de "referente a la persona de que se habla". Sobre todo este último sentido, al igual que el ejemplo "esto es propio de ti", implica que es una característica (la jaula) personal de uno mismo, y por tanto hecho por uno mismo (cada uno se construye su caracter).
- Lo importante de Tulip y Somali-land es definir un lugar cercano y otro remoto para dar la idea de que los límites de la jaula no están en ninguna parte. Así que uso Lugo como lugar cercano (en España, para dar coherencia a la traducción en español de España) e Irán como lugar lejano. En el caso de Tulip, además, se escribe el estado porque es la costumbre allí, al poder existir varios Tulip en diversos estados. Como en España solo hay un Lugo, no hace falta especificar "Lugo, Galicia" ni nada parecido. Más aún: en la traducción oficial al castellano de la película no hacen mención a dichos límites, simplemente dicen "y en ella seguirás, vayas donde vayas", seguramente porque la gente de aquí no iba a entender esas referencias.
- La conclusión final es que cada uno es su propia jaula, así que plasmo esa interpretación al final del párrafo.

Lamento la ingente cantidad de licencias que me estoy permitiendo, pero para batir al español arcaico de guifa hay que hacerlo así.

## Intento inicial, 210 caracteres.

> Te denominas un alma libre, una "salvaje", y te aterroriza que alguien pueda enjaularte. Pues nena, ya estás en una jaula, hecha por ti. Y no limita al oeste con Tulip, Tejas, ni al este con Somalilandia. Va contigo. Pues doquiera que corras, siempre te encontrarás a ti.

Comment: ¡Gran recorte! El _Porque_ podría ser _Pues_. Ah, y si contáramos palabras, podríamos hacer una conversión _te denominas_ -> _Denomínaste_, _te aterroriza_ -> _aterrorízate_.

Comment: @fedorqui Menudas traducciones rarunas iban a quedar así... :-D

Comment: guifa sería imbatible :P

Comment: @fedorqui justo iba a decir que si consideramos palabras con proclisis, pues ganaré yo.  Quizás tendré que volver al pasado para resurgir los pronombres átonos con mesoclisis (tipo, "comprartelosé", "dirteloíamos")

Comment: Somalilandia se considera hoy en día un estado fallido. Inmerso en una guerra civil, poco reconocido internacionalmente, leo que hasta 1960 fue protectorado británico y luego se unió a Somalia Italiana para formar Somalia. La novela es de 1958, así que seguramente en esas fechas era relativamente conocido por aparecer en las noticias (como si nos hablaran ahora de Darfur, por ejemplo).

Comment: ¡Ganaste! Enhorabuena por ofrecer algo tan correcto y corto a la vez. Ahora recoges el testigo para continuar con el juego :)

Answer (score 5):

Quizás tome demasiado libertad (ni digo que fluya bien), pero...

## Español con suaves toques arcaicos, <strike>145</strike> <strike>142</strike> <strike>141</strike> <strike>136</strike> 126 golpes

> Veste alma libre, una fiera, y temes ser presa. Y, niña, es así.  En una jaula que hiciste.  No fina ahí en Tulip, Tejas, ni ý na India. Está do vayas, ca do huyas, toparteás.

## Y tratándola de usted,  <strike>133</strike> <strike>128</strike> 118

> Vese alma libre, una fiera, y teme ser presa. E, hija, es así.  En una jaula que hizo.  No fina ahí en Tulip, Tejas, ni ý na India. Está do vaya, ca do huya, toparseá.

Una explicación como ha pedido Carlos en los comentarios (es algo muy frecuente en codegolf)

```
Veste       - proclisis de «te ves» (me veo así == me considero)
alma libre  - no creo poder reducirlo más 
                (sinónimos posibles incluyen espíritu libert(ad)o, no conformista, etc)
una fiera   - «fiera. 2. adj. Dicho de un animal: Salvaje o agresivo»
                es preciso la «una» para evitar que «fiera» se interprete
                como adjetivo de alma
y temes     - tienes miedo de
ser presa   - un preso es alguien enjaulado o encarcelado
                (tmb. es el antiguo participio de prender, por lo que se podría
                interpretar como la acción «ser prendida» ~ «ser enjaulada»)
Y           - en este contexto, sinónimo de «bueno, bien, pues» ~ «vamos a ver» 
niña        - todas las variantes (niña/nena/neña/hija tienen 4 caracteres)
es así      - así == presa/atrapada/encarcelada
En una
jaula       - la única palabra más corta sería «caja» que no tiene tanto
               sentido.  «trena» es más de cárcel.
que hiciste
No se fina  - «finar» antes significaba «acabar/terminar», ello se evidencia
                con el significado en portugués de «acabar; findar; finar-se» 
                (Priberam), y en asturiano «Acabar, poner fin a [daqué]» 
                (DALlA), «finir» ~ «Tenir fi; acabar.» (GDLC).  Antes
                tenía «acotar»: «acotar. 3. tr. Delimitar el ámbito o espacio
                de algo.»
ahí en      - «ahí» para mantener esa idea de por un lado 
Tulip, Tejas
ni ý        - «y³. 1. adv. dem. desus. allí.», es más frecuente ver con tilde
na          - «1. contracc. desus. En la.» (DLE)
India       - Somalilandia no existía tantos siglos ha, uso el
                más o menos coetáneo equivalente de la India (==lugar muy lejos)
Está        - el presente también implica futuro y es más común que en
                en el inglés con esa referencia.
do          - «donde»
vayas       - incluso mejor sería fueres, pero son más letras jaja.
                el subjuntivo contiene la idea de «-ever» (así evitamos «doquiera» 
ca          - «porque»
do          - «donde»
huyas       - otra vez, mejor sería «huyere», el subjuntivo evita necesitar «doquiera»
                en este caso, el correr del inglés refiere a dar la fuga, 
                intentar escapar, por lo que «huir» sale muy bien.
toparteás  - mesoclisis de «te toparás», «te encontrarás».  
               viene de la construcción original del futuro topar+haber, 
               es decir «topar has» que permitía por mucho tiempo «toparte has»
               y constan ejemplos en una palabra como «toparteas» que
               hoy llevaría tilde en la última a: toparteás.  Es cierto
                que era idea de Rodrigo.  Suelo evitarlo en castellano
                por ser el término más común en asturiano («atopar» e
                él) y poco usado en el castellano pensinular, no obstante,
                era mucho más frecuente en el castellano áurico que
                en el moderno, por eso creo que cabe mejor que «hallar»
                que tenía antes.
```

Evolución:

- 145 (informal) - intento inicial
- 142 (informal) - sustitución de «allí» por «ý»
- 141 (informal) - sustitución de «corras» por «huyas»
- 136 (informal) - sustitución de «Somalistán» por «la India», 
                     «cosa (fiera)» por «una», «hallaraste» por «toparaste»
- 128 (informal) - sustitución de «acotarse con» por «finar en»,
                     empleo de la contracción «na»
- 133 (formal) - subiendo la formalidad
- 128 (formal) - sustitución de «Somalistán» por «la India»,
                     «cosa (fiera)» por «una», «hallarase» por «toparase»
- 118 (formal) - sustitución de «acotarse con» por «finar en»,
                     empleo de la contracción «na»

Comment: Esta respuesta mola pero tiene mucho que explicar... :-D

Comment: @CarlosAlejo hecho (con algunos pequeños cambios)

Comment: Y acabo de ver que las reglas están puestas, y no puedo usar «TX» por «Tejas» =/

Comment: Por cierto, si estos son los toques arcaicos suaves, estoy deseando ver los fuertes. :-D

Comment: @CarlosAlejo me he limitado a las que figuran en el diccionario. La putada es que en no contando los espacios, la proclisis no me ahorra nada. Voto por alternar entre número de letras y número de palabras

Comment: Nótese que [Somalilandia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somalilandia) es un nombre real, por lo que deberíamos ceñirnos a él. Hay quien usa _Somalistán_, pero por su carácter de estado fallido. No creo que sea válido en este contexto, pues para cuando se escribió la novela no era tal.

Comment: Por cierto, le leí esta propuesta de traducción a mi mujer y me dijo que parece sacado de _El sí de las niñas_. ¡Vetustas palabras que transportan a otra época! Magnífica respuesta.

Comment: @fedorqui curiosamente, en la traducción oficial ([según Wikiquote](https://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Desayuno_con_diamantes)) no hacen referencia a los límites, supongo que por ser muy regionales y no entenderse en la adaptación: _Y en ella seguirás, vayas donde vayas._

Comment: @CarlosAlejo he encontrado una versión en PDF del libro tanto en inglés como en castellano y en ninguno encuentro este fragmento. ¿Será que la web de donde lo saqué lo asoció a la novela cuando realmente pertenece solamente a la película? Creo que la clave aquí está en o bien usar Somalilandia como nombre propio, o bien usar una expresión equivalente como bien haces tú.

Comment: @fedorqui [es de la película](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054698/quotes?item=qt0460777), definitivamente.

Comment: Por cierto, en la versión formal se me hace raro que sigas usando el apelativo "niña", que no concuerda con dicha formalidad. ¿Tal vez habría que cambiarlo por otro menos cariñoso y más formal?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo sí, probablemente *hija* quedaría mejor.

Comment: Tienes 24 horas para intentar bajar tres caracteres y ganar :) @CarlosAlejo ¡ojo al dato! Parece que uno de los dos ganaréis, así que id pensando un fragmento si queréis, para presentarlo mañana.

Answer (score 5):

Here's mine, which I did without looking at others' because I wanted to just start fresh.  I came by my Spanish in Mexico but have been living elsewhere for a long time, so let's hope I managed to be consistent.  I did try to be concise but not at the expense of being faithful to the original and natural in my choice of expressions.  MS Word tells me my character count is **223** -- significantly less than the 283 Word told me were in the original.

> Tú te llamas bohemia, 'salvaje,' y tienes terror a que te pongan en una jaula. Pues bien, mi amor, ya estás ahí. Tú misma te la hiciste. Y no está definida de poniente por Tulip, Tejas, ni de oriente por Somalia. Estás en la jaula por doquier. Porque adonde vayas, vas a topar contigo misma.

If there's something small that doesn't ring true, but can be fixed -- please don't stand on ceremony, just dive it and fix it.

- Edited out the double "vayas" at the end, and added a colon (Carlos Alejo). New character count: 223.
- Adjusted the *terror* part.  New count: 222, I think.

Comment: Nice try, that's the spirit!

Comment: Nótese que [Somalilandia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somalilandia) es un nombre real, por lo que deberíamos ceñirnos a él.

Comment: _Tienes un terror que te pongan en una jaula_ sounds weird to me. I would either add a colon: _tienes un terror**:** que te pongan en una jaula_ or specify "el": _Tienes **el** terror que te pongan en una jaula_. Also note the double _vayas_ to the end.

Comment: Muy interesante la aportación de "bohemia". El diccionario lo define como "que se aparta de las normas y convenciones sociales". Si no estás sujeto a normas o convenciones es que eres libre de hacer lo que quieras, que va con el espíritu de la frase.

Comment: @fedorqui - I took "adonde vayas vayas" from a charming children's poem that I have fond memories of.  But this is not a children's poem and I don't mind it getting the red pen. // I guess you changed your mind about Somalilandia (I read another comment). // Maybe we could remove the colon like this: *y tienes un terror a que te pongan en una jaula*?

Comment: If we remove the colon you'll and add _a_ after _un terror_ you'll have one more character :P The part of Somaliland is controversial historically, I assumed _Somaliland_ is the proper name historically, but I may not be right. Just pick one and justify if needed.

Comment: @fedorqui - My German spouse says Somaliland was the German name of the country.  I suppose if we want to check into historical accuracy for how Spanish was used at the time the novel was written, that would add a whole other layer to the game. // As you can see from my character count, I was aiming for a translation I liked, first, and conciseness, second.  What do think about my idea for the alternative to the colon?

Comment: aparente001 (nice nickname by the way), this has become a very deep issue and we are learning a lot about history here. I in fact asked about it yesterday in [history.se]: [What was the name of the region, Somalia, British Somalia or British Somaliland?](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/36221/19545) and haven't received an answer yet. I don't know how it was said in Spanish back in the 60s. Now we just say Somalia, whereas Somalilandia goes for the failed state within the country. By the way, I discovered this part was introduced in the script of the movie! So it is from around 1961.

Comment: Regarding _y tienes un terror a que te pongan en una jaula_, I think it is not correct. You are mixing indefinite (_un terror_) with definite (_a que te pongan_). I would say either of these: _Y tienes terror a que te pongan..._ or _Y tienes terror a que te pongan..._, see we are using either _un_ or _a_, but not both.

Answer (score 4):

## 195 caracteres

> Te proclamas alma libre, una "cosa bravía", y temes ser enjaulada. Pues, niña, ya lo estás. En una jaula hecha por ti. Y no aquende Tulip, Texas, ni allende Somalistán, sino donde vayas. Pues no cuenta adónde corras, siempre acabas yendo hacia ti misma.

Comment: Agradable actividad para esta hora del día... el problema es que yo debería estar trabajando. Hace algún tiempo conocí la palabra _procrastinar_ y mi participación en este sitio se redujo a la mitad...

Comment: Muy buena, lo de "aquende" y "allende" me ha dejado anonadado.

Comment: Nótese que [Somalilandia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somalilandia) es un nombre real, por lo que deberíamos ceñirnos a él. Hay quien usa _Somalistán_, pero por su carácter de estado fallido. No creo que sea válido en este contexto, pues para cuando se escribió la novela no era tal.

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, me di cuenta después de ver las otras respuestas. "Somalia" parece ser lo mejor. En todo caso, obviamente mi traducción hace rato quedó de las últimas. "Gracias por participar".

Comment: @fedorqui Pero no estoy de acuerdo con ceñirnos a "Somalilandia", traducción literal. Podría ser "de Japón a la China", y quedaría bien igual.

Comment: Tienes razón. Lo incorrecto es decir _Somalistán_ por _Somalilandia_. Ahora bien, dado que es una traducción de una expresión o forma de decir algo, si se traduce el concepto de cualquier otra forma (como la que indicas) está bien, cierto.

Comment: Eso sí, en la novela se indica que la protagonista proviene de Tulip, Tejas.

Answer (score 4):

## 161 caracteres

> Te dices alma libre, "salvaje", y temes te enjaulen; bien, nena, en
>   jaula estás, hecha por ti. No limita al oeste con Tulip, Texas, ni al
>   este con Somalía: está doquier vayas pues, adonde corras, contigo
>   toparás.

Comment: Muy buena la opción de "contigo toparás": respeta el sentido original a la perfección a la par que elimina muchos caracteres.

Comment: ¡Gran aportación! Nótese que [Somalilandia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somalilandia) es un nombre real, por lo que deberíamos ceñirnos a él. Eso, o explicar el uso de _Somalía_.

Comment: @fedorqui "Somalilandia" es, además de un país moderno, el nombre inglés (castellanizado) de la región. De hecho, siempre supuse (aunque seguramente me equivoque) que a la colonia británica era más común conocerla como "Somalía Británica" y no "Somalilandia Británica" como dice Wikipedia; incluso, dado que "Somalilandia" es el nombre inglés, hasta me parecería redundante, en español, aclarar que es la británica, ya que a la italiana sí que siempre se la conoció como "Somalía Italiana".

Comment: @JMVanPelt Las referencias que he encontrado parecen indicar que lo común era llamarlo Somalilandia Británica. Y es cierto, no resulta simétrico con la italiana. Estoy descubriendo la historia de esa región a medida que investigo con esta pregunta, por lo que cualquier dato añadido será más que agradecido. De hecho, [acabo de consultarlo](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/36221/19545). Dado que el texto es de 1961 (de la película), lo ideal sería mantener lo usado en esas fechas por coherencia histórica. Por cierto, ¿pusiste tilde a Somalia adrede?

Comment: @fedorqui Toda la vida dije "Somalía", y después de escribir esto comprobé que no es correcto; pensaba que se podían usar ambas formas, como "Rumania" y "Rumanía". Por lo que he visto, en inglés se llamaba _Somaliland_ a toda la región (de ahí que dijeran _Italian Somaliland_) que, en italiano, era _Somalia_ (véase el [mandato de la ONU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_Territory_of_Somaliland) _Trust Territory of Somaliland / Amministrazione Fiduciaria della Somalia_) que reemplazó a la Somalia Italiana en la posguerra.

Comment: Ajá, entonces la duda sería ver cuál fue el concepto utilizado en español durante esos años para llamar a la región, si _Somalia_ o _Somalilandia_. Por cierto, en la pregunta de [history.se] comentaron que _Somalilandia_ probablemente también incluye la Djibuti actual, que era Somalilandia Francesa.

Answer (score 3):

Es un ejercicio muy interesante. Let me try.

## 159 caracteres

> Te crees alma libre, "salvaje", y temes te enjaulen. Niña,
>   ya estás en una jaula, hecha por ti. No limita al oeste de
>   Tulip, Tejas, ni al este de Somalilandia. Está donde vas. Pues
>   aunque huyas, la jaula eres tú.

Comment: ¡Gran aportación! Nótese que [Somalilandia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somalilandia) es un nombre real, por lo que deberíamos ceñirnos a él. Eso, o explicar el uso de _mundo Somalí_ (que debería ir en minúscula de hecho).

Comment: Gracias por la correción. Hoy aprendí algo nuevo.