# Uso de "ý" en el español medieval

Tags: historia, palabras-raras, letras, español-medieval

Guifa [nos ha enseñado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20250/12637) que en español existió la letra *ý*, hoy día desaparecida. Se puede encontrar en textos como el siguiente:

> *[...] me obligo de dar e pagar a vós, Mateo Magno, vezino de la dicha civdad qu'está ý presente o a quien vuestro poder ubiere, ocho ducados que suman y montan tres mill maravedís [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Carta de obligación", 1566 (España).

¿Durante qué periodo estuvo vigente esta letra? ¿Cuándo desapareció? ¿Se usaba en alguna otra palabra además de suelta? Y suelta, ¿servía para algo más además de como sinónimo de *allí*?

Comment: Bueno, la letra *ý* pervive principalmente para algunos nombres (Aýna, Ýñigo). Pero en el momento en que se usaba para significar *allí*, no había tildes tal y como los conocemos hoy — la acentuación es moderna (y como el antiguo *nos*, siendo una palabra tónica, se suele tildar en los libros aunque el DRAE no lo indique). En aquellos momentos habría sido simplemente *y*

Comment: @guifa en el CORDE los ejemplos me aparecen como _ý_, con la tilde. Pensaba que sería así para distinguirla de la conjunción _y_, aunque ahora que lo pienso, la conjunción _y_ es relativamente moderna, ¿no? Antes se diría _e_ o _et_.

Comment: la *y* como conjunción llega más o menos con el s. XVI. De hecho, lo normal para la edición de textos antiguos que empleaban el símbolo ⁊ es usar el año 1500 como punto de cambio: si el texto viene antes, se transcribe *e*, después, *y*.

Comment: En [esta pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18579/a-qu%c3%a9-se-debe-la-aparici%c3%b3n-de-la-forma-aynno-en-textos-del-siglo-xiv) ya nos había llamado la atención que figuraran algunas _ý_ dentro de palabras; recuerdo haber visto varias pero (si bien no le había dedicado demasiado tiempo) no descubrí que su uso siguiera alguna regla.

Comment: @JMVanPelt ¡gracias! ¡Llevo todo el día tratando de averiguar de qué me sonaba la ý! :-)

Comment: Otra recompensa que parece que quedará desierta :O

Comment: @fedorqui se agradece mucho la intención, en todo caso. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**¿Se usaba en alguna otra palabra además de suelta?**

No solo en "alguna otra palabra", sino en una importantísima para la evolución del español actual: **el antiguo pretérito imperfecto del verbo *haber***:

> *Por Dios, amigo, si yo tal cosa fiziesse, **seervos ýa** muy falso amigo.*
>   <sub>Juan Manuel, *Lucanor*</sub>
>
> *E **seguirse ýan** a esta opinión ynposible otros ynconvinientes ynnumerables.*
>   <sub>A. Torre, *Visión*</sub>
>
> *¿Y **marauillarte ýas** si demás que desesperado me metiesse yo aquí hermitaño?*
>   <sub>Valdés, *Mercurio*</sub>

De este uso proviene la desinencia **-ía** con la que se forma hoy día [el condicional simple](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wGKVlTpykzCxbIgl) (véase 23.15c).

La evolución de los ejemplos anteriores sería:

- *seer(vos) **ýa*** -> *ser(vos) **hía*** -> (os) ser**ía**
- *seguir(se) **ýan*** -> *seguir(se) **hían*** -> (se) seguir**ían**
- *marauillar(te) **ýas*** -> *maravillar(te) **hías*** -> (te) maravillar**ías**

**¿Cuándo desapareció?**

Lo cierto es que las tres formas convivieron durante varios siglos: buscando en el CORDE, tanto ***seguirse ýa***, como ***seguirse hía***, como ***se seguiría*** aparecen en diferentes textos desde mediados del s. XIII hasta principios del s. XVII, momento en que dejan de aparecer las dos primeras (salvo en citas) y en que, entiendo, se estableció la última forma como la correcta.
Buscando ***ý*** a secas, tampoco salen usos propios más allá del s. XVII.

Comment: ¡Me ha encantado la respuesta! Muy interesante el origen de la forma del condicional.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, me encanta. Me fascina la evolución del lenguaje.

Answer (score 3):

El uso de *ý* como (terminal) *í ~ i ~ y* parece haber sido más común en los siglos XV al XVI según estos resultados de búsqueda del [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) (primero **1284** - último **1626**):

[image: muestra]

Nótese también su uso en *reýa* y palabras anticuadas, como *roýdos*, *otrosý*, *ansý* (> *ansí* > *así*) etc.

---

Ademas, hay estos nombres propios que todavía llevan tildes:

- *Aýna* (municipio)
- *Laýna* (apellido)
- *Ýñigo* (apellido)
- *Ýscar* (nombre)

---

**Fuentes**

> <sup>f) La tilde se escribe sobre los grafemas vocálicos</sup>
>   <sup>... En los casos en que el acento de la palabra recaiga sobre un fonema vocálico /i/ excepcionalmente representado con el grafema y, se escribirá la tilde sobre esta letra si la palabra debe acentuarse gráficamente según las reglas de acentuación. Estos raros casos se dan en topónimos y antropónimos escritos con una y vocálica ortográficamente arcaica (v. cap. I, § 6.1.2.1.2c): *Aýna* (municipio español), *Laýna* (apellido).</sup>
>
> > <sup><sup>Información adicional. En las ediciones de textos antiguos en las que se respetan las grafías originales, donde la letra y puede aparecer en otros contextos distintos de los que le corresponden a este grafema en la actualidad, se puede ver escrita la y con tilde como resultado de aplicar a las palabras con grafías desusadas las reglas de acentuación hoy vigentes: *otrosý*, *ansý*, *roýdos*, *aýna*, *Ýñigo*, *Ýscar*. En estos mismos textos, el adverbio tónico *ý*, que significa ‘allí’, se escribe con tilde diacrítica (v. § 3.4.3.1, segunda información adicional) para diferenciarlo de la conjunción copulativa átona y: *«Non tornaron por ello desque lo ý metieron»* (Berceo Domingo [Esp. c1236]).</sup></sup>
>
> - [*Ortografía de la lengua española: 3.2 **Principios por los que se rige el sistema de acentuación gráfica del español***](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fupVvbcsRxbFstPx) (p.222-223)