# Tiempos pasados para expresar deseos futuros

Tags: verbos, pretérito-imperfecto, futuro

Vamos con un nuevo episodio de "preguntas de carretera". Hoy, volviendo a casa en el coche tras una comida abundante en un pueblo cercano, exclamé en voz alta:

> Me **echaba** yo una siesta al llegar a casa que no veas...

Y ahí mi cerebro reaccionó pensando: ¡Un momento! ¿Por qué estoy usando un tiempo pasado (pretérito imperfecto) para expresar un deseo que ha de cumplirse inmediatamente o en un futuro próximo? ¿Qué sentido tiene esta construcción? ¿Por qué se usa así? ¿Tiene nombre esta forma de usar el pretérito imperfecto? ¿Es de uso común fuera de Andalucía o España?

P.D.: Dos horas de siesta cayeron, dos...

Comment: Es súper común, tanto en castellano como otros idiomas ibéricos, y que sepa, tanto en la península Ibérica como en las Américas, que el pretérito imperfecto vaya reemplazando el condicional.

Comment: En efecto y como dice @guifa tanto en castellano de este lado del Atlántico como en portugués brasileño se usa, e incluso más en PT-BR que en castellano diría yo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Comenta la RAE](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wnKrOXODEcgvpUFC) en su *Nueva Gramática* en el párrafo 23.11l que la asimilación entre el pretérito imperfecto y el condicional viene dada por la evolución histórica de este último (como se vio [en una respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21986/12637) a [otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20262/12637)):

> Comparten también [ambos tiempos verbales] segmentos morfológicos, puesto que el antiguo auxiliar del condicional (*cantar-hía*) era un imperfecto. El condicional simple se considera un "futuro del pasado", y el imperfecto, un "presente del pasado". Así pues, cuando el imperfecto prospectivo aparece subordinado a un pasado, designa una situación posterior a un pretérito y adquiere, en consecuencia, un significado próximo al del condicional.

Expone los siguientes ejemplos para el uso prospectivo del pretérito imperfecto:

> *Llamé a tu oficina y me dijeron que hoy no ibas.
>
>   Ya creí que nos echaban el multazo.*

Nótese como se puede sustituir *ibas* por *irías* y *echaban* por *echarían*. A partir de aquí se expone cómo el pretérito imperfecto se puede usar para hechos frustrados en el párrafo 23.11m, poniendo como ejemplo los siguientes:

> *Mi avión salía mañana a las 23:50, pero se canceló el vuelo por la huelga de pilotos.*

Y a partir de aquí, se contempla el caso del uso del **pretérito imperfecto con valor desiderativo**, expuesto en el párrafo 23.11n con el siguiente ejemplo:

> *[...] derecho me iba al río, si no os viera.*

En este caso el pretérito imperfecto depende de otro imperfecto: *viera*, pero también puede verse introducido por otro tipo de construcciones (párrafo 23.11o):

> *¡De buena gana te quitaba la nariz de un bocado!
>
>   Yo que vos me lo pensaba.*

Y en el párrafo 23.11p, precedido de un gerundio u otras construcciones temporales:

> *Bajando un poco el precio, segundo que vendías.
>
>   Ahora mismo me comía unas sardinas.*

Este último caso es similar al propuesto en la pregunta, siendo el marco temporal "al llegar a casa".

Sobre uso, la cosa viene de antiguo. Buscando en el CORDE, uno de los ejemplos previamente expuestos es del año 1583:

> *—Parece —respondió Juliano— que nuestro cuerpo naturalmente sigue el movimiento del sol, que a esta hora se encumbra y a la tarde se derrueca en la mar; y así es más natural el subir a los altos por las mañanas, que el descender a los ríos, a que la tarde es mejor.
>
>   Según eso respondió Sabino —yo no tengo que ver con el sol, que derecho me iba al río, si no os viera.*
>
> Fray Luis de León, "De los nombres de Cristo, libros I-III" 1583 (España).

No comentan en ningún caso algún límite regional para este uso desiderativo del pretérito imperfecto, por lo que debe ser algo ampliamente usado en todos los países de habla hispana (como afirman @guifa y @pablodf76 en sus comentarios a la pregunta).