# ¿Hay acentos sobre una Y?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, letras

¿Hay en español palabras de 2 o más sílabas con el acento en la Y? suponiendo que hubiese tal palabra o que en el futuro exista la palabra, ¿Se le pondría tilde si cumple con las reglas? Suponiendo, si existiera la palabra *sylaba* como esdrújula, ¿llevaría tilde?

Comment: Posible duplicada. Puedes consultar las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20262/12637) para información sobre la grafía _ý_.

Comment: @Charlie Es cierto que la respuesta de brazofuerte (que ni siquiera es la seleccionada) puede servir para esta pregunta, pero la pregunta en sí es muy diferente. Esta habla de las normas actuales, mientras que la otra trata del uso histórico, cuando las normas ortográficas ni siquiera existían.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, desde 2010 con la nueva ortografía.   Eso dicho, solo ocurre hoy en día en nombres como *Aýna* o *Ýñigo* pero si *sílaba* se escribiese con *y*, llevaría tilde: *sýlaba*.

En el español antiguo, aunque no llevase tilde, era común encontrar la *y* en sílaba propia (donde se esperaría una *i* con tilde en la ortografía moderna).

Comment: Me alegro de volver a verte por aquí :)