# Translation-golf VII: "Lose yourself" by Eminem

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés, rima

El juego consiste en tomar un fragmento de un texto en un idioma extranjero y traducirlo al español. Gana quien consiga usar el menor numero de caracteres, manteniendo el sentido del texto.
Aquí tenéis enlaces a [las normas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/13628) y a un [contador de caracteres](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/) (no cuentan signos de puntuación: solo letras y números).

*The goal is to take a fragment of text in a foreign language and translate it to Spanish. The winner will be whoever manages to do it with the least amount of characters, while keeping the text's meaning.*
*Here you have links to [the rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/13628) (in Spanish) and to a [character counter](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/) (punctuation doesn't count; only letters and numbers do).*

El siguiente fragmento está extraído de la cancion *[Lose yourself](https://www.google.es/search?q=lose+yourself)*, compuesta por el conocido rapero Eminem, y tema principal de su película autobiográfica [*8 Mile*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298203/):

*The following fragment is taken from the song [Lose yourself](https://www.google.es/search?q=lose+yourself), composed by famous rapper Eminem and main theme of his biopic [8 Mile](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298203/):*

> His palms are sweaty, knees weak, arms are heavy
>   There's vomit on his sweater already, mom's spaghetti
>   He's nervous, but on the surface he looks calm and ready
>   To drop bombs, but he keeps on forgettin'
>   What he wrote down, the whole crowd goes so loud
>   He opens his mouth, but the words won't come out
>   He's chokin', how, everybody's jokin' now
>   The clocks run out, times up, over, blaow!
>
> <sub>*293 caracteres*</sub>

Mi propuesta de traducción (que confieso que he hecho un poco más larga de lo habitual, para mayor efecto):

*My translation proposal (which I confess to have made a bit longer than usual, for a greater effect):*

> Sus manos están sudorosas, las rodillas débiles, los brazos le pesan.
>  Ya hay vómito en su suéter, los espaguetis de su madre.
>  Está nervioso, pero en la superficie parece calmado y listo
>  para lanzar bombas, pero se le sigue olvidando
>  lo que escribió, todo el público hace mucho ruido.
>  Abre su boca, pero las palabras no quieren salir.
>  Se está ahogando, ¿cómo? Ahora todos están haciendo chistes,
>  los cronómetros se van a parar, ¡se acabó el tiempo! ¡Final! ¡Bum!
>
>  <sub>*361 caracteres*</sub>

Como dirían en la película: "*DJ, kick it!*". ¡Diviértanse!

*As they would say in the movie: "DJ, kick it!". ¡Have fun!*

---

### Fin de la partida

**Vencedor**: [**CarlosAlejo** con 166 caracteres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20976/13628)
Victoria *cum laude* además, ya que ha conseguido mantener la rima original :-O ¡Mi enhorabuena!

Medalla de plata: [**aparente001** con 179 caracteres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20981/13628)
Medalla de bronce: [**Diego** con 216 caracteres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20969/13628)
Diploma: [**dockeryZ** con 307 caracteres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21015/13628)

Gracias a todos por participar!

Comment: Hace nada vi el segmento de John Oliver sobre el plagio de _Lose yourself_ en Nueva Zelanda, y todavía me estoy riendo. En cuanto pueda aporto mi propuesta.

Comment: creo que no hemos cerrado ninguna de las otras. Si alguien quiere entretenerse creando una respuesta nueva para alguna de las preguntas viejas (por diversión) pues perfecto, pero estarían fuera de concurso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### <strike>241 187 179 181 168 167</strike> 166 caracteres

> Miembros sudados, flojetes,
>   pasta de mami jitada en su suéter,
>   tenso en calma, ariete
>   de bombas y en el éter
>   la letra. La basca alborota.
>   Abre la boca: la voz no brota,
>   se ahoga. ¿Qué? ¿De chacota?
>   ¡Bum! El tiempo se agota.

- La voz inglesa *sweater* derivó en el español *[suéter](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YeanG5Q)*.
- La onomatopeya *[bum](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6HtJr2q)* (para representar el sonido de un golpe o explosión) viene en el diccionario.

Primera actualización:

- Una de sinónimos desconocidos: *[gormar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JMIc2ul)* como "vomitar".
- Espero que "tenso en calma" se entienda como "nervioso con pinta calma".
- Resulta que *[bombear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5pavn5E%7C5pby2Zk)* se puede usar como "arrojar o disparar bombas de artillería".
- Uso "la letra" para indicar que era lo que estaba intentando recordar, lo "anotado".
- *[Gentío](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J6Kv0TF)* es un sinónimo de "multitud".
- *[Coña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AiDpZIq)* es sinónimo de "guasa, burla".
- Me permito una licencia con "fin del juego" para indicar el concepto de que se agota el tiempo (como en *game over*).

Segunda actualización:

- Aun a costa de arriesgarme a un mayor número de caracteres, he respetado el esquema de rima consonante A-B-A-B-C-C-D-D de la canción original. No he podido evitarlo.
- Se puede usar *[patas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM)* coloquialmente para referirse a las piernas de una persona.
- Para poder rimar uso *brazo pesado* en singular. Entiendo que el brazo que sostiene el micrófono le pesará más que el otro.
- Otra de sinónimos raros y desusados: *[jitar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MUccdGZ)* por "vomitar".
- Cambio "preparado para bombear" por "armado de bombas", que refleja la misma idea con menos letras al tiempo que mantiene la rima.
- Uso del *[éter](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H3TdIDM)* como sinónimo de "vacío espacial": las palabras siguen en ninguna parte en concreto.
- Uso *[basca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5ABjIv2)* como "gentío".

Tercera actualización:

- Me dicen que la rima en realidad es A-A-A-A-B-B-B-B. Para conseguir tal rima deberé relajar un poco los primeros versos y hacerlos asonantes, aunque de momento mantengo una rima consonante en los cuatro últimos.
- *[Malmeter](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O3UwRC1)* puede significar "poner a alguien en contra de un tercero". En este caso el símil sería que su brazo se está poniendo en su contra, poniéndole en contra de la situación.
- Un *[catéter](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7xDXeGo)* es un tubo sonda que se introduce en el organismo, se usa aquí como símil del conducto por donde va a ir soltando las bombas al público.
- La palabra *[chacota](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8SFHnp3)* resulta que rima y describe muy bien la situación: es sinónima de "broma, burla". Aprovecho para simplificar esa frase.

Cuarta actualización (a la desesperada):

- Se usa *[apéndices](http://dle.rae.es/?id=38Lkt7h)* como sinónimo de *extremidades* para referirse a los brazos y las piernas ("parte del cuerpo animal unida o contigua a otra principal"), y se le aplica el adjetivo "flojo" a ambos, en la forma diminutiva [-ete](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H3Sohu5) para mantener la rima. A fin de cuentas, si el brazo te pesa es que lo tienes flojo.
- Y ya de paso meto "manos" en la definición de *apéndice* y digo que están todos sudados. Ya sé que esto puede ser sintetizar y abstraer demasiado, pero va a ser la única forma de seguir en la competición.

Quinta actualización (tras comentarios del OP):

- Cambio "catéter", que no ha tenido mucha aceptación, por *[ariete](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3YgSmAg)* ("máquina militar que se empleaba antiguamente para batir puertas o murallas, consistente en una viga larga y muy pesada"). Mantiene la rima asonante y el grupo *-ete-*. Quitamos la idea visual de "bombas [por un tubo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=are90sf#DMxWR4E)" que daba el catéter y plantamos la idea de "soy una máquina de guerra que os va a reventar a bombas".
- Mantengo la idea del "éter", pero explico: la palabra "éter" da una sensación poética de "vacío, olvido". Valga como ejemplo el siguiente texto (negritas mías):

  > *Bárbara sentía su espíritu desprenderse también e incorporarse a aquella reverberación de la tierra en reposo, tan íntimamente ligado a esa tierra, como si le estuviera traspasando en aquellos momentos toda su sangre joven, que huía, que se iba para abajo a teñir las rosas de mañana... La sangre se iba abajo y el espíritu ascendía; ascendía ya sólo atado por aquella vena azul que le temblaba en las sienes... Flotaba ahora aletargado en el **éter**, ingrávido y libre como una estrella solitaria... De pronto habían desaparecido su fatiga y su impaciencia de un minuto. Tampoco sentía curiosidad, y aunque nada la sujetaba ya al suelo, no pensaba en transponer el umbral de aquella puerta arrancada con fatiga a la tierra y al tiempo.*
  >
  > Dulce María Loynaz, "Jardín. Novela lírica", 1935 (Cuba).

Sexta actualización (y espero que última):

- No sé qué ida de olla me dio con "apéndices", cuando tenemos *[miembros](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PDfN5jE)* con un significado mucho más claro: "cada una de las extremidades del hombre o de los animales articuladas con el tronco". Y me quito una letra.

Pequeños retoques:

- Cambio "mamá" por *[mami](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O6KVLaO)* para mejorar el ritmo.

Comment: @walen ahí llevas unas cuantas. :-)

Comment: @walen bueno, cuando te atragantas una de las reacciones posibles es toser. En todo caso, había entendido mal el verbo, lo arreglo y listo.

Comment: @walen madre mía, como tenga que hacer la rima que tú dices me muero. Podría tal vez conseguirlo con una rima asonante y así relajo un poco la misma, tal y como hace la letra original, pero no sé si quedaría con la misma gracia en español.

Comment: @walen ya tienes la rima consonante en los cuatro últimos, dame tiempo y saco una al menos asonante en los cuatro primeros. :-)

Comment: @walen pues mira, al final casi consigo la rima consonante total (me han faltado palabras en el diccionario), pero me ha quedado bastante poética la traducción...

Comment: Carlos, me haces el favor, ¿te grabas leyendo tu entrada?  Es que soy torpe con la poesía y quisiera saber cómo arreglar las sílabas en el ritmo que estás imaginando.

Comment: @aparente001 nunca dije nada de que mi versión tuviera ritmo (de hecho no lo tiene), solo que tiene rima (casi) consonante (lástima del primer verso).

Comment: Ah, ya veo, perdón.  Y la rima ya es suficiente reto, creo yo.

Comment: The *catéter-éter* rhyme is impressive, and I like the *éter* line, but when I read the *catéter* line I thought, "Huh?" and had to consult the notes.  Seems a bit too far-fetched to me.  Even after reading the notes.  Maybe I think too literally (e.g. how can a bomb possibly fit in a catheter tube?).... Could you add a bit to the *chacota* explanation?  I didn't know this word, and the DRAE definition isn't helping me get what's going on when you combine it with *de*. But there's great stuff here and I especially like *patas, flojas, éter, brota, ahoga, agota* -- amazingly creative.

Comment: @aparente001 ¡gracias! Sobre lo de _chacota_, al ser sinónimo de "broma" pensé que se podría usar igual que en "estar de broma", en cuyo caso se puede eliminar el verbo en la expresión por sobreentenderse. Y lo del catéter, es que no hay más palabras en el diccionario que acaben en "éter", así que me tendréis que conceder esa licencia. No es tan descabellada si no te la tomas al pie de la letra, claro. :-)

Comment: @walen - Just my two cents: I agree about *catéter* but not about *éter*.  I understood what you were doing with *éter* without having to go down to the notes.

Comment: @walen he modificado la parte del "catéter" que veo que no ha tenido mucha aceptación, y explico un poco más la idea que quería dar con lo del "éter".

Answer (score 2):

### <strike>219</strike> 216 caracteres

> Palmas sudorosas, rodillas tiemblan, brazos pesan.
>   Basca la pasta de mamá en su sudadera.
>   Nervioso aparenta calma.
>   Listo para dar caña, aunque olvide el verso
>   preparado. La peña enloquece.
>   Abre la boca mas nada sale.
>   Atragantado, todos ríen.
>   El reloj agota el tiempo, BUM!

Uso "pota" como sinónimo de "vomitona" y "peña" como sinónimo de "público o audiencia".

Actualización 1: uso [basca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5ABjIv2) en el sentido de "regurgitar". Lo estoy forzando un poco al convertirlo en verbo, pero he aprendido una palabra nueva :-)

Comment: @walen pues no os lo vais a creer, pero aunque "pota" sea de uso común en el habla y muchos la entendemos, no viene en ningún diccionario (ASALE no la recoge y para la RAE solo significa "calamar basto").

Comment: @CarlosAlejo + walen, oído cocina. En cuanto pueda dedicar un poco de tiempo.

Comment: "¿Oído cocina?" // I especially like *Nervioso aparenta calma.*  I tried and tried to get something to work with *aparentar* and you got it!

Comment: Es como si alguien (un camarero por ejemplo) gritase a la cocina "una comanda de bravas y un plato de boqurones" y se responde desde la cocina "Oído cocina" en plan "Recibido. Ponemos la orden a la cola".

Comment: Me gusta la frase.  Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Version 4 with meter and rhyming

#### <strike>159 168 169</strike> 179

I did what I should have done in the first place -- I listened to (and watched) the original.

> El palmo sudado, 
> Pierna débil, todo pesado 
> Vomitose, fideo casero 
> Agitado... mas en externo 
> Calmo y listo a 
> Tirar bomba, pero olvida 
> La letra, la gente grita 
> Abre boca, no sale nada 
> Se ahoga, y la risa 
> Y la hora se acaba

Performance notes

Each line has a slight pause in the middle.  For example, you would chant the beginning kind of like this (and to make the meter work, you'll kind of gloss over the D in *todo*):

> El palmo, 
> sudado 
> Pierna débil, 
> to' pesado 
> etc.

Comment: @walen - glad to get things started.  I forgot to say, I was inspired by the Dominican song "Da Pa' lo' Do'" (Rita Indiana).

Comment: @walen desafortunadamente debo discrepar. Las palabras _pesao, agaitao_ y _anotao_ no existen en español, luego no son válidas para el juego. Las palabras _sudá_ y _pa_ existen pero no con el significado usado en la traducción. La palabra _na_ existe pero solo se acepta en Chile y Venezuela, por lo que si se usa el resto de la traducción debe ser consistente con el habla de alguno de estos países. Si yo escribiera tal y como hablo con mi acento andaluz ganaría todas las partidas. :-)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Perdón, una pregunta, ¿conoces "Da Pa' lo' Do'"?

Comment: No la conocía, estoy leyendo la letra ahora mismo. Entiendo la forma en que está escrita, ya te digo que yo hablo andaluz y sé comerme la mitad de las palabras cuando hablo, pero eso no quiere decir que deba hacerlo cuando escribo. También entiendo que estamos traduciendo una canción, pero si nos ponemos a escribir tal y como hablamos, ¿dónde ponemos el límite?

Comment: @walen entiendo vuestro punto de vista al respecto, y me encantaría compartirlo, pero insisto: ¿dónde ponemos el límite? ¿Me aceptaríais lo siguiente si trato de imitar el habla andaluza? _Deo' sudao', letra olviá, tos de coña._ Y si rebusco en el habla de Cádiz ya ni os cuento... :-D ¿Y si os aseguro que "ro" es como se dice "rodilla" en mi barrio? Podría inventarme pronunciaciones y usarlas. Ese es el motivo de esa regla, simplemente.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - I remember back near the beginning, someone wrote an entry with a special vocabulary: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20250/9385.  I reread the rules and I think # 6, 7 and 10 can help us here.  Please don't hesitate to (a) challenge me on some specific words and (b) write a regional entry using your own natural mode of expression (but with plenty of explanations so people like me will be able to follow along).

Comment: The answer you link had a special vocabulary, indeed, but you can look up any word from that answer in the dictionary as it just uses very old (but valid) Spanish. If you want a challenge just prove that the words in my first comment here appear in the dictionary and have the meanings you claim. Just check my answer to see that I link every word I use to the DLE.

Comment: @walen - Thanks, that made the revision a breeze.

Comment: @walen - I don't need *pa'* any more, but I was wondering for future reference whether https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/pa would make it acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

#### 307 caracteres

> Sus manos sudadas, débiles rodillas, brazos pesados
>
> Ya tiene vómito del espagueti de mama en el suéter
>
> Tiene nervioso pero parece por fuera tranquilo y listo
>
> para sobresaltar pero se le sigue olvidando lo que escribió
>
> El público hace tanto ruido. Él abre la boca pero no salen las palabras
>
> Tartamudea. Todos bromean
>
> Se acaba la hora
>
> no más tiempo
>
> Fin
>
> Blaou

Comment: ¡Gracias por participar! Anímate y no te limites a la traducción literal, busca sinónimos que te hagan ahorrar espacio, expresiones que te hagan concretar y sintetizar las frases: el objetivo es dar la misma idea que el original en el menor espacio posible. ¡A jugar!

Comment: This was basically my first draft, I don't do translations often, but this seemed like a challenge and an opportunity for good practice.  I do participate in Duolingo's translation features every once in a while though.  

I read through everyone else's translation after I posted mine and was quite enlightened.

Comment: I like what you did with *tartamudea*.