# Translation-golf IX: V's introduction

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés, aliteración

El siguiente texto es la introducción que V hace para presentarse formalmente a Eve Hammond en *V for Vendetta*:

> Voilà! In view, a humble vaudevillian veteran, cast vicariously as both victim and villain by the vicissitudes of Fate. This visage, no mere veneer of vanity, is a vestige of the vox populi, now vacant, vanished. However, this valorous visitation of a by-gone vexation, stands vivified and has vowed to vanquish these venal and virulent vermin vanguarding vice and vouchsafing the violently vicious and voracious violation of volition.

El texto contiene un cierto juego de palabras, al introducir el mayor número posible de veces palabras que empiecen por la letra `v`. Una posible traducción podría ser:

> Veamos! A primera vista, un humilde veterano de vodevil en el papel de víctima y villano por vicisitudes del destino. Este visaje, ya no más velo de vanidad, es un vestigio de la [vox populi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c4J6bch), ahora vacua, desvanecida. Sin embargo, esta valerosa visión de una extinta vejación se siente revivida y ha hecho voto de vencer el vil veneno de estas víboras en avanzada que velan por los violentos viciosos y por la violación de la voluntad.

Para esta edición del juego, cada palabra que empiece por `v` descuenta una letra del total de caracteres. Mi propuesta son 347 caracteres, como 26 palabras empiezan por `v`, mi total es **321** (347-26).

Recordad seguir [las normas publicadas en *meta*](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481). Como siempre, la traducción fiel [con menos caracteres](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/) gana.

---

Ganador @JMVanPelt con 287 caracteres!. @JMVanPelt, como ganador es tu privilegio comenzar el siguiente juego si quieres. Si no, en dos días cualquier otro usuario puede proponer un nuevo juego.

Gracias a todos!

Comment: ¡Cómo me gusta este texto! Lo flipé cuando lo oí en el cine la primera vez y lo sigo flipando cada vez que lo escucho. ¡Acepto el reto más que encantado!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo tenía mis dudas sobre si se prestaría bien al translation-golf. Lo he propuesto con un poco de miedo. Me pareció que el "juego dentro del juego" con las uves podía ser interesante (ya que me pareció genial la idea del último tuyo con lo de la rima) y hasta consideré "bonificar" las palabras que empezasen por "V" incluso más todavía (o que no contasen) pero luego pensé que era "demasiado" experimento y que podía desvirtuar el juego (aunque podría discutirse...). A ver qué pasa. Espero que de para una partida interesante y que lo disfrutéis enormemente.

Comment: Una pregunta: dado que "voilà" es un término francés que no corresponde al idioma del texto original, ¿podemos dejarlo nosotros también en francés? A fin de cuentas, aunque no la recoge el DLE es una expresión de sobra conocida...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo yo para el mio me curé en salud y no lo puse. "Vox populi", en cambio, viene en el DRAE. De acuerdo a las normas no podemos usarlo (lo siento), porque entonces abrimos la puerta a "esto no está en el DRAE, pero es de sobra conocido" y ya hemos tenido ejemplos en otras partidas donde no lo permitíamos. Este es el primer ejemplo [que me viene a la memoria](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20969/5481). Aunque las normas no cubren expresamente _anglicismos_ o palabras prestadas de otros idiomas, sí dicen que todo lo usado debe estar en DRAE o el de americanismos.

Comment: Y eso que las normas básicamente las redacté yo mismo. :-) Muy bien, acepto la puntualización y cambio mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 309 caracteres - 22 V's = 287 caracteres

> ¡Velay!, un humilde y vodevilesco veterano vuelto, por las vicisitudes del hado, víctima y villano sustituto. Esta faz no es mera pátina de vanidad sino vestigio de la Vox pópuli, ya vacía y desvanecida. Mas tal valiente visita de un viejo rencor revive y jura vencer a esa runfla venal y virulenta que promueve el vicio y accede a que se viole, con violenta avidez y vileza, la voluntad.

---

[Velay](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bTNdqUR): interjección usada para dar por cierto o asegurar lo que se dice

[Runfla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WqFqW9E): Serie de varias cosas de una misma especie. Muchedumbre

Comment: Esta entrada de juego es de @JMVanPelt. Al editar yo la respuesta (que es _community wiki_) ha desaparecido su nombre al tener yo más _edits_. Como un _rollback_ no lo arreglaba dejo este comentario para que quede constancia de que es su entrada del juego.

Answer (score 2):

### 330 caracteres - 32 V's = 298 caracteres

Me he liado un poco con la última parte, pero allá va:

> ¡Ahí va! Ves aquí a un humil veterano del vodevil, a quien las vicisitudes del hado colocaron como víctima y villano. Esta vis, no más válida vanidad, es un vestigio del *vox populi*, ya vacante, vacío. Pero esta valiente visita de una vieja vejación, se vivifica y vota vencer a los viciosos, verminosos, venenosos y virulentos vanguardistas que velan por los violentos vicios y la voraz violación de la voluntad.

Explicaciones:

- Voilà: no viene en el DLE, pero al ser una palabra que tampoco pertenece al idioma original del texto, considero oportuno dejarla igualmente en su idioma original, además de ser una expresión muy conocida.
- [Humil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Koh4oIY): sinónimo en desuso de "humilde".
- [Hado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JxsZGaS): sinónimo de "destino", tiene la misma raíz etimológica que "fate".
- [Vis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bubBGiP%7CbubxMcv): dado que "vis a vis" es "cara a cara", considero "vis" como "cara".
- [Vox populi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c4J6bch): expresión latina recogida por el DLE, se respeta así el original.
- [Votar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c4FFqHA): se puede usar como sinónimo de "jurar", dado que significa "hacer voto a Dios o a los santos".

---

**Actualización 1:**

- Para cumplir las reglas del juego, cambio "voilà" por "ahí va". Misma cantidad de letras y mismo bonus por "va".

Comment: Lo curioso es que el DPD acentúa [_vox pópuli_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=p%F3puli)